# Adding the headers-more-nginx-module to NGINX

Tags: nginx, centos7

I've been trying so hard to resolve this myself over the last week or so but I'm banging my head against a brick wall now!

Long story short, I'm getting a CORS error and I've been trying to fix the issue using the **add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;** command in every place I can think of and with commas and single quotes in various places. My nginx install is a mainline release 1.15.3 on CentOS 7.

I soon figured that this module must be installed by default and adding the above line to the location / {} block in default.conf should be fine. I then added the extension to Firefox to make sure it worked (as a temp measure) and found that I got a 500 error. So now (not sure why) I have the extension disabled and the above line added to the default.conf file and I'm still getting the 500 error - which is good in a way! Now I want to install the -more- module to get over the 500 error I am now getting, as to my understanding the basic header module cannot deal with 500 errors.

My biggest problem at the moment is not being able to add this module to my nginx install. Looking online I see instructions for recompiling nginx with the module using the ./configure command (./configure --prefix=/opt/nginx --add-module=/path/to/headers-more-nginx-module) but I have no configure file in my nginx root directory (which is actually etc/nginx). I have no idea how to handle this really and could do with some advice please.

I did run nginx -V to list the modules that where supposedly installed with my instance of nginx but there was no mention of any header module so my assumption of the basic module being installed out of the box could also be wrong.

Comment: Well, I'v managed to download the source and recompile nginx with the more_headers module included. I've also successfully loaded the module via the nginx.conf file. Not sure how to actually use the module though now....

Comment: I've added **load_module /etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so;** to the **/etc/nginx/nginx.conf** file. Before adding the necessary lines to use the module I tried to restart nginx - it errored! Looking at the status it told me **/etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so" is not binary comp...nx.conf:7**. Looking into this I found that this may be something to do with a signature key. The modules key not matching nginx's key??

I'm very much out of my comfort zone here and need some help. How do I reslove this please? ANY help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Well thanks for your help everyone!!